Date Stamping Status Changes in a SharePoint List without Power Automate
As of current, I have a SharePoint Classic list (through work we can only use Classic) which is used to track many things, of which status changes is one of them. There are around 6 statuses a job can be on, and I want a way of date stamping when a status change occurs, E.g. the job status changes from "Design" to "Manufacture". We do not have access to Power Automate, which seems to be used everywhere to do this now; is there a way to do this without Power Automate, I have access to workflows so would be happy to do it through this.
Thanks in advance :)

Unfortunately, without Power Automate, it is not possible to date stamp status changes in a SharePoint Classic list. Classic workflows do not have the capability to achieve this functionality. However, if you have access to SharePoint Designer, you can create a workflow that sends an email notification when a status is changed. You can also use SharePoint Designer to create a custom form that includes a field for the status and a field for the date. When the status is changed, the workflow can update the date field with the current date and time.
